# Entrance door warped when it’s warm outside

Tags: wood, doors

The entrance door to my apartment warps when temperatures rise. When outside temperatures are below 15–20°C, this effect is hardly noticeable, but in summer (I would say above 25°C) there is a noticeable “bend” in the door, the lateral view of which is best described as:

```
(|
```

The deformation is such that it takes a lot of force to make the latch make contact with the strike plate. To unlock the door from outside, I need to pull at the knob to reduce friction between the latch and the strike plate.

The door appears to be a massive wooden door from the early 1970s. I’ve painted the inside white some ten years ago.

The hinges are simple barrel hinges. The don’t seem to have any lock mechanism, thus I would assume the door could simply be lifted off the hinges. From my point of view, that makes it unlikely that the door is simply expanding in the heat and bending because it is wedged in between the two hinges and has nowhere to go—rather, I’d expect uniform thermal expansion to lift the door a bit off the top hinge.

The door separates the hallway of my apartment (which is neither heated nor air-conditioned) from an open gallery (meaning the outside of the door is exposed to outdoors temperatures).

I’ve thought of attaching an angle iron (similar to [this one](https://youtu.be/eQEPQEE-RlM?t=653)) to the door—in winter, when the door is straight—hoping that will prevent it from warping next summer. Given the shape of the door, I’d have to go for 20×20mm.

Will this successfully prevent the warp? Any other suggestions?

Image of the door below.

[image: image of door]

Comment: You painted the interior face... are all the other edges painted? Is that paint in good condition?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate To be more accurate, the **entire** door was painted before, I just painted **over** the interior face. Apart from some cosmetic issues (fingerprints and the like), the paint is in good condition on all sides, nothing coming off, no obvious signs of moisture getting into the wood.